# How do I print the original string for JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here is my javascript example code using jquery

```js
$(".class").append("<a class='button-link' onclick='myFunction('"+ p1 +"' , '" + p2 + "')'>Click Me</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result in HTML is like this

```
<a class="button-link" onclick="myFunction("p1' , 'p2')'></a>
```

But I want the result is like this

```
<a class="button-link" onclick="myFunction('p1' , 'p2')"></a>
```

Comment: Try using escaped double quotes for the onclick attr:
```$(".class").append("<a class='button-link' onclick=\"myFunction('"+ p1 +"' , '" + p2 + "')\">Click Me</a>");```

Comment: Ok thank you , i will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var p1 = 'p1';
var p2 = 'p2';

var myFunction = (a0,a1) => { console.log(a0, a1) }

$(".class")
    .append('<a class="button-link" onclick="myFunction(\'' + p1 + '\' , \'' + p2 + '\')">Click Me</a>');

console.log( $(".class").html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline handlers are generally considered to be pretty poor practice and are difficult to manage, in part due to quote-escaping issues like these. Rather than using an `onclick` attribute, attach the handler properly using Javascript, and it should be much easier to read, debug, and think about:

```
const a = $("<a class='button-link'>Click Me</a>");
a.on('click', () => myFunction('p1', 'p2'));
$(".class").append(a);
```

```js
const a = $("<a class='button-link'>Click Me</a>");
a.on('click', () => console.log('foo'));
$(".class").append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
</div>
```